# How can I make my html website display the page route that I am on?

Tags: html, url, routes

I want to make my html website display the route of the current page that I am on like this:
website:
[www.example.com/example](http://www.example.com/example)
content:
you visited the example page
website:
[www.example.com/page](http://www.example.com/page)
content:
you visited the page page

I know how to do this with flask but how would I do this with plain html, or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location API on the window object:

```
window.location.href
```

**EDIT:**

The bellow snippet is how i would have done it with vanilla javascript:

```js
const paragraphEl = document.querySelector('.not-found-page p')

const url = window.location.href

const idx = url.search(/.net\//)

const route = url.substring(idx+5)

if (rest !== 'js') {
  paragraphEl.innerText = `Sorry, the current route (${window.location.href}) is not available.`
} else {
  window.location.href = 'https://website.com/some-other-route'
}
```

```html
<section class="not-found-page">
  <p></p>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that it says on the html page, "Sorry the {route} does not exist", but if it a valid route it goes to the right page and doesn't display that? Here is an example:     URL: mysite.com/h8dshfds                                                                                                                        Page Content:                                                                                                                                         Sorry, there is no page called h8dshfds.

Comment: I edited the snippet in my answer to best fit your request.